# In Caffe, how to modify a specific conv layer's behavior?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

In Caffe, how to modify a specific conv layer's behavior?

I think I can modify conv layer Class c++ code, but I don't know how to get a conv layer's name in conv layer Class, so I can't use if() to make my code only work on a specific conv layer.

Can anyone help me, Thank you very much~

Answer (score 0):

Layer's name is part of its [`LayerParameter`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L327). To access it, simply

```
const LayerParameter& param;
std::cout << "My layer's name is: " << param.name();
```